# su: bashlia: No such file or directory

Tags: freebsd

```
[user@freebsd ~]$ su root 
Password: 
su: bashlia: No such file or directory
```

How come i cannot switch user to root account?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it isn't finding the shell you use called "bashlia".  Maybe one of the following will work for you:

```
sudo su
```

or

```
su - root
```

or

```
sudo -u root /bin/bash
```

Comment: user  is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: `su -s /bin/sh`